# How does health work exactly? How much damage should enemies do?

Tags: world-of-dungeons, streets-of-marienburg

I need some advice on how to run the game [Streets of Marienburg](http://gremlinlegions.blogspot.co.nz/p/game-hacks.html) (based off the World of Dungeons hack of Dungeon World).

I'm really interested in running it but am unsure how the players aren't just going to straight-up die the first combat encounter they run into.

Rules for attributes:

> Characters have six Attributes. Determine their score by rolling 2D6 in order: 
>   On a 2, the value is -1. 
>   On a 3-6, the value is +0. 
>   On a 7-9, the value is +1. 
>   On a 10-11, the value is +2. 
>   On a 12, the value is +3.

Rules for health:

> You have one Stamina die (d6) + extra Stamina dice equal to your CON.
>   Roll all your Stamina dice and keep a number equal to your Level to determine your current Health. If you have a CON penalty, you do not reduce your Stamina dice, but instead subtract the penalty from each die you keep, minimum 1.

It seems like at level 1, you'd have a maximum of 6 health, of course with a chance of having lower health. Every weapon in the game does 1d6 damage, more or less. So how can I run a combat encounter when the first problem or failure could lead to their immediate death?

If anyone could have a read of the rules or if you've played World of Dungeons or Dungeon World before and can give me some advice, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

World Of Dungeons 1979 is invoking the spirit of early DnD. It was quite usual for characters to die on their first adventure, and this is likely intended to be the same.

I remember a session where each member of my group churned through several, tossing the screwed up character sheets into quite a considerable pile by the end. Characters making it to second level and beyond were rare and precious.

It's not usually done like that these days (and that's probably for the better). Decide for yourself whether you want to play a game like that now.

Comment: "Roll all your Stamina dice and keep a number equal to your Level to
 determine your current Health." It looks to me like high initial CON is more of a "choose the best of the three dice to determine your starting health" and therefore the maximum is still 6 HP for a character level 1, 12 HP for a character level 2, ...

Comment: Yep; I see what you mean. I'll edit.